# Which FlushMode in Hibernate commits when you call session.flush()?

Tags: java, hibernate, commit

I read that whether a call to `session.flush()` commits or not depends on the `FlushMode` that is set. However, I don't know which `FlushMode` does this. I want the session to be flushed and commited. Which FlushMode should I use?

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around. you can flush when calling commit. These are the flushmodes in Hibernate: [FlushModes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)

### ALWAYS

The Session is flushed before every query.

### AUTO

The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.

### COMMIT

The Session is flushed when Transaction.commit() is called.

### MANUAL

The Session is only ever flushed when Session.flush() is explicitly called by the application.

---

I think you are looking for AUTO. So the session is flushed on Commit

Comment: I require this information for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642219/how-to-commit-batches-of-inserts-in-hibernate) purpose. Am I using the FlushMode right?

Comment: Actually I don't know if committing without prior flushing has really sense. So what is supposed to happen when you commit() with MANUAL flush mode?

Comment: AUTO is the default value for FlushMode.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say vice versa - whether Hibernate flushes or not on commit depends on [FlushMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html).

Comment: OK, so which FlushMode does both?